# What may cause my app display more than one icon on screen

Tags: android

My app re-create its icon every time after a re-install or device-reboot on specific device (MEIZU MX3 -> a popular device in China).

I have checked my `uses-permission` and no `INSTALL_SHORTCUT` found.

Can anybody give me some instruction to fix this? Thanks in advance for any help you are able to provide.

[image]

Comment: which icons you are talking about, app icons or something that is created in public directory

Comment: @PankajNimgade app icon. The icon you click to launch app.

Comment: app usually creates a separate icon every time u change package name..

Comment: @Vikram Thanks, but we never change our app name or package name since online.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have used

```
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

with more than one activities in manifest. make sure, it is specified with launcher activity only. App icons for all those activities is displayed which have main category specified.

Comment: Do you mean `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER`? I only use it with one activity.

Comment: Ok. Have you specified any launchmode for different activities in manifest?
can you post manifest?

Comment: e.. I have fix it. It seems that is a problem since I use `ShortcutBadger` library. I disable `ShortcutBadger` for MEIZU devices and bug seems gone.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it.

If you are using `ShortcutBadger` library. Disable it for MEIZU devices.

`ShortcutBadger` need some permissions may write something confused the launcher.

`<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>`